# Sample rate for iPhone audio recording

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

What's the lowest optimal sample rate for audio recording on iPhone while still yielding good file size?  Currently I am using 44.1kHz but it produces file that's way too big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "optimal".  22.05kHz would still be good enough for most music.  11.025kHz would be more than adequate for recording speech.  It all depends on what you're doing with the audio.  I recommend using your ear to determine the best rate.

Answer (score 13):

On the iPhone with the built-in microphone, you're going to get a maximum of 8 kHz. If you use a headset, you can get 44.1 kHz. If you're using the built-in mic and setting your recording sample rate to 44.1 kHz, you're upsampling the audio, which is unnecessary and generates the big files you mention. Also, make sure you record in mono. That cuts the file size in half.

If you always want to record at the best rate, you should ask the hardware:

```
size = sizeof(sampleRate);
err = AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate,
    &size, &sampleRate);
```

For voice, you can just always record at 8 kHz. For music, you want the best quality so use the sample rate that the hardware is running.

Comment: source for the sampling rates please?

Comment: @bubakazouba The original iPhone's microphone had an 8 kHz sample rate but newer devices support higher https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/OptimizingForDeviceHardware/OptimizingForDeviceHardware.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you want 8 kHz, as others have said.  This is the rate that land-line telephones use.  If you are doing speech recognition, though, you might want to increase the frequency to 16 kHz, which is what IBM's speech recognition requires for "high quality" (see their [API docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-audio-formats)).

Wikipedia's article on [sample rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate) gives a good chart of sampling rates and their uses:

```
 8000  Land-line telephones
11025  One-quarter of CD quality
16000  Voice-over-IP
22050  Half of CD quality, could be used for older audio (e.g. 78 RPM records)
32000  Camcorder audio
44100  CD quality
48000  Professional audio equipment
```